# Can you tell me who owns this patent now?

Tags: us3039165

This patent was owned by my Uncle, Albert Floyd Old. Which now has passed away. I was interested in who is the owner now?

Answer (score 2):

*No one owns it*. This patent was issued on Jun 19, 1962. It would have expired in the 1970's.

Comment: Well, the _public_ owns it now :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily search for patents on [Google Patents](http://google.com/patents) using their publication number.

See [Google.com/patents/us3039165](http://Google.com/patents/us3039165) (it even has a link to *this* page):

> **Method and apparatus for production of lightweight aggregate from dust**
>
> Publication number: US3039165 A
>
> Publication type: Grant
>
> Publication date: Jun 19, 1962
>
> Filing date:  Apr 28, 1954
>
> Priority date:    Apr 28, 1954

Seems like it used to be owned by [Solite Corp](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=solite%20corp), but [old patents expire 17 years after grant or 20 years from filing, whichever greater](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/3803/8289). This means that *everyone* has been free to use it since 1979.