# Does Re-issue of US patent have extended expiry?

Tags: reissue

The original priority date was in 1994 [US5662332](http://www.google.com/patents/US5662332) so my assumption was that it had expired, but upon searching Public Pair using the application number (US 08/544,306) it comes up that it's under Re-Issue and still patented. So my question is, is the patent actually expired or does the re-issue extend the term somehow, or is there something else that's extending the term beyond the 20 year window that I'm missing?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate expiry from the US5662332 Re-issue is just publication of information. Here is another answer to calculate the same [How do you determine a patent's expiration date?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/3801/11895)

**MPEP 1405    Reissue and Patent Term [R-11.2013]**

> 35 U.S.C. 251 prescribes
>
> > the effect of reissue on the patent term by stating that "**the Director
> >     shall… reissue the patent… for the unexpired term of the original
> >     patent.**"
>
> The maximum term of the original patent is fixed at the time the
>   patent is granted. While the term may be subsequently shortened, e.g.,
>   through the filing of a terminal disclaimer, **it cannot be extended
>   through the filing of a reissue**. Accordingly, a deletion in a reissue
>   application of an earlier-obtained benefit claim under 35 U.S.C. 120
>   will not operate to lengthen the term of the patent to be reissued.