# I am the Granddaughter of Wladimir Senutovitch who created the patent. What is the status at this time?

Tags: patent-lifetime

In reference to the patent: [US1996490](https://www.google.com/patents/US1996490)

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you determine a patent's expiration date?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/3801/11895)