# Expiration date for patent 5824100

Tags: expiration

In reference to the patent: [US5824100](https://www.google.com/patents/US5824100)
What is the expiration date for this patent?  Thank you.

Comment: Looks like on October 30, 2016

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you determine a patent's expiration date?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/3801/11895)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like on October 30, 2016. 
The patent term adjustment does not found in USPTO pair. Use http://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/patents/law/How_to_Locate_Patent_Term_Information.docx