# Has the Borland 32-bit SEH patent expired?

Tags: algorithms, us5628016

In reference to the patent: [US5628016](https://www.google.com/patents/US5628016).

Is this patent expired? Can other people now implement SEH on 32-bit without opening themselves up to being sued?

Comment: Duplicate [How do you determine a patent's expiration date?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/3801/11895)

Comment: See: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_of_patent_in_the_United_States