# Anybody can use this process?

Tags: us5356811

In reference to the patent: [US5356811](https://www.google.com/patents/US5356811)

If anybody want to do manufacturing of stabilize aloe vera gel , they can do by its own with another method ? and if they want to do with this methods , they can do ?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you determine a patent's expiration date?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/3801/11895)

Comment: Hi Lalit, welcome to Ask Patents! Per Pushpak's suggested reading, the patent you're referring to is expired, so the answer is yes. Are you still curious about the rights you might have if the patent *wasn't* expired? Or maybe you were aware of the fact that it was expired and you'd like to know what you can do now that it is? I'm going to hold off on closing this as a duplicate for now, so definitely let me know if you are looking for a more detailed answer to one of those questions, or if the fact that it's expired does answer your question.