# Patent expire limit

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [US7841131](https://www.google.com/patents/US7841131)

Is this a design patent? Wouldn't it be expired as the 14 year limit is up?

Comment: no its not design patent.duplicate of [How do you determine a patent's expiration date?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/3801/11895)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you determine a patent expiration date?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/how-do-you-determine-a-patent-expiration-date)

Comment: The possible duplicate doesn't answer the question about whether it is a design patent (although I'm sure there are other answers that do).