# Is US 6,608,366 B1 in the public domain?

Tags: expiration, us6608366, us7183630

In reference to the patent: [US6608366](https://www.google.com/patents/US6608366)

Is US 6,608,366 B1 in the public domain?

Answer (score 1):

No, [US 6,608,366 B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US6608366) and the continuation patent [US 7,183,630 B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US7183630) (from the same application) are not in the public domain. I double-checked the [Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) records to verify. Both of these patents are enforceable until April 15, 2022.

Please also refer to a related question describing [how to calculate patent expiration dates](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/3803/14417).