# PRIOR ART REQUEST: US7,051,342 - Method and system for remote automation of object oriented applications

Tags: prior-art-request, post-grant, microsoft

This is a prior art request for [U.S. Patent No. 7051342](https://www.google.tl/patents/US7051342) "Method and system for remote automation of object oriented applications", belonging to Microsoft Corporation. The patent expires 2021-10-22, was filed 2004-10-22 and was granted 2006-05-23.

The first claim and the claims related to it are:

> 1. In a distributed computing system including a client computer having a multi-tasking, threaded, operating system, and plural threads in a client process sharing processor resources, the client computer communicating with plural remote computers providing business services applications on behalf of the client process, the computing system handling object references requested by said plural threads in the client process, the client computer comprising: 
>      at least one processing unit and a memory;
>    means for providing a common operating system thread to handle the runtime resolution of object reference requests;
>    means for receiving from a first thread running in the client process, a reference request for a first object providing business application services;
>    means for determining by the common operating system thread, a first remote computer providing access to the first object and establishing a first communications channel with the first remote computer;
>    means for receiving from the first thread running in the client process, a reference request for a second object providing business application services;
>    means for determining by the common operating system thread, a second remote computer providing access to the second object and establishing a second communications channel with the second remote computer;
>    means for receiving from a second thread running in the client process, a reference request for an object providing business application services;
>    means for determining by the common operating system thread, that the reference requested by the second thread resolves to the first object; and
>    means for providing business applications services to the client process via the established communications channels;
>    wherein said business application services provided to the client process comprise data received via the established communications channels and wherein said data received was obtained by the business application services from one or more additional remote computers comprising data application services.
>
>    2. The computing system of claim 1 wherein the data received via the established communications channels is sent from the first and the second objects.
>    3. The computing system of claim 2 wherein the first and second objects obtained the received data from plural of said additional remote computers comprising data application services.

Comment: How did you get the date of expiry?

Comment: @DonQuiKong I calculated knowing that patents filed on or after 1995-o6-o8 have a term of 17 years from filing.

Comment: Patents filed on or after 1995-o6-o8 have a term of 20 years from filing. Patent filed before 1995 have a term of 17 years from grant. There are a few exceptions. The answer to this question covers them: https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/3801/18033

Comment: I fail to understand what is the actual question :(

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like [Remote procedure calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) (RPC) and the [DCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model) [marshaller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: For this to be a helpful answer it would need more detail. For example more fully specifying what these things are, when do they date from and how are they like the claims?

Comment: I agree. It sounds like you have specific technical knowledge so I'm sure with a little effort this could be a very valuable answer. Perhaps define the acronyms and link to documentation that provides dates.

Comment: This is an improvement as you have provided links. However link only answers are usually considered inadequate. If you could summarize why you think these links are prior art even if you just quote the appropriate text from the sources it would greatly improve the answer. Thanks.